# Android Developer Console, what do the percentages for "All apps" and "Top 10" mean?

Tags: android, google-play, android-market-filtering

Recently I've uploaded an app in the category productivity. It is an commissioned app for a company that now has one single app in the Android app market. It is a free app and people have been downloading it since a couple of weeks. So now I'm looking at the Statistics page to see how things are going.

Google provides very nice and clear charts and data about the downloads. However, there is one aspect of the Statistics page that is still a bit mysterious.

I'm looking at "Active Installs on Devices" and you can display data based on Android version, Device, Country, Language, App-version, Provider. For example when I select Country, I see something like this:

```
                  Your       All apps in
                   app       productivity
Netherlands     18   7,86 %     1,33%
India           15   6,55 %     2,63%
Brazil           9   3,93 %     1,77%
etc.

Top 10 countries for productivity
United States     28,64 %
South-Korea       10,51 %
Japan              8,34 %
etc.
```

So there are 18 active installs in The Netherlands which is 7.86% of all the active installs of my app, this I understand. But my question is:

**What do the percentages for "All apps in app-category" and "Top 10 *country/language/android verison* for app-category" mean?**

I've looked in Google help and found "Manage you account -> Statistics for apps", but it mentions nothing about the All apps and Top 10 data. And btw the "All apps" and "Top 10 percentages" are not displayed when you select Device or App-version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**All apps in productivity**: Means that all apps which are in the category "productivity" have (on average) that many installs in that country. The average "productivity" app has 1,33% of its installs in the Netherlands.

**Top 10 country version for productivity**: Means that the highest percentage of installs for apps in category "productivity" is in those countries. The average "productivity" app has most of its installs (28,64%) in the USA.

Likewise for languages and android versions.

Comment: Okay, I understand. That makes sense, and I guess data based on language or country could be useful.

Btw I doubt that the perentages for, for example, "All apps in Productivity per Android-versions" or "Top 10 Providers for Fotography" will yield useful results for anyone. But I guess Google just likes to aggregate things.

Anyway, thanks that answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

means just they are giving stastics about for that category , how people downloading with different versions of the android phone

Answer (score 0):

These values are not related to your app only, but to all apps in the Google Play.